# how do I force render a chart on non-displayed tab to get svg data?

Tags: extjs

The ExtJS chart must be rendered in order for the svg data to be plucked from the html element. This chart is on tab2 in my test app, with tab1 being the active tab. How do I force render the chart without the user seeing it so I can grab the svg data?

Added

forceLayout: true,
 deferredRender: false,
 layoutOnTabChange: true,
 defaults:{hideMode: 'offsets'}

to parent tab of chart but did not help. What this does do is force the chart div to show up in the html node tree - however the svg data is a skeleton without the chart details .... very strange since switching to tab2 shows the chart in all its glory! The full svg data only shows up in the html node tree after switching back and forwards between the 2 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Got around this by putting the ExtJS chart on the front tab so it gets rendered in time, where the chart is "offscreen" and cannot be seen by user. Using layout: 'fit' only shows the first, top container where I process the chart svg data, and the rendered chart is within the second, lower container with its svg data available but unseen on gui. There maybe a more elegant way but I could not find one.